# Right way to compute pairwise significance for a multiple choice survey question?

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, multinomial-distribution

Say I ask people via survey, "Pick your one favorite option: A, B, C, or D." What is the proper way to compute pairwise significance between the answer options? Can we say whether there is a statistically significant difference in the rate that users picked A vs B, or A vs C, etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "pairwise significance between the answer options"?

Comment: Unless respondents can pick more than one option, there is no way to compare response categories.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: +1 I'v upvoted, but still have a question: how many people (roughly) are asked? and how many votes for the least popular answer would you expect?

Comment: Thanks! Total it's roughly 200 responses. The most buckets are ~80 responses and least is 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to compare the number of votes for A to the number of votes for B, you can proceed as if the A/B voters were your total sample (i.e. condition on the sum of A and B). Then you would test if the probability of voting for A is 0.5.

Given you have asked enough people, such that you would expect at least roughly 10 votes for A, say, an approximate chi-squared test would be fairly accurate. For a chi-squared test of the hypothesis "A is as likely as B", the test statistic becomes very simple. Let $a$ be the number of votes for A, and $b$ be the number of votes for B, then $T=(a-b)^2/(a+b)$ has approximately a $\chi^2$ distribution with one degree of freedom, and you get the $p$-value as $pval=1-F_{\chi^2;1}(T)$.

When you do several pairwise tests, however, you should correct for multiple testing. For testing the hypothesis that A,B,C or all four options are equally popular, you can use a similar $\chi^2$-based tests for goodness of fit (Pearsons or G-test).